# If two continuous functions defined on $\mathbb S^1$ have the same Fourier coefficients of all order then they are the same.

Tags: fourier-analysis, haar-measure

I am studying Gelfand transform and Wiener's theorem from the lecture notes given by our instructor. Here I came across the following definition about Fourier coefficients of a continuous function defined on $\mathbb S^1.$ Here is the definition $:$

> **Definition** $:$ Let $f \in C \left (\mathbb S^1 \right ).$ Then one defines the $n^{\text {th}}$ Fourier coefficient of $f$ by $\widehat {f} (n) = \int_{\mathbb S^1} f(z)\ z^{-n}\ dz,$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$ and the integration is with respect to the Haar measure on the group $\mathbb S^1.$

Just after the definition a result has been mentioned as a remark which states the following $:$

> If two continuous functions defined on $\mathbb S^1$ have the same Fourier coefficients of all order then they are the same.

But I find it difficult to prove this fact. Could anyone kindly help me in showing this?

Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

Comment: I think we need to use that the functions $z\mapsto z^n$ form a *complete orthogonal system* in $L^2(\Bbb S^1)$.

Comment: @Berci I found that $$\left \langle z^n, z^m \right \rangle_{L^2 \left (S^1 \right )} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i (n - m + 1) t}\ dt.$$ Am I right? I think I made a mistake here.

Comment: We could use the advanced theorem that $\{e^{inx}: n\in \Bbb Z\}$ is a complete orthogonal system in $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$, so if $<f-g,e^{inx}>=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ then $f=g$ almost everywhere so $\{x\in [-\pi,\pi]: f(x)=g(x)\}$ is dense in $[-\pi,\pi]$. But I suppose there is a more elementary proof.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet can you provide me some reference where I can find the proof of the fact you have used?

Comment: It's in many texts on Measure Theory or on Lebesgue Integration or on Hilbert Spaces or on Fourier Series. But I don't recall any specific titles.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I already had a measure theory course earlier but I couldn't find the result you mentioned there. That's why I am asking for references. Thanks.